# Preview Multi Page PDF in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

PDF's when more then one page, will show as an icon rather then previewing the entire document. This is the default behaviour with the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Can the default behaviour be changed so that the document always loads up for a preview before sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be changed. `MFMailComposeViewController` provides no API for what you want.

Comment: Thanks, web view it will be then.